# How to manage one consistent documentation for different implementations of one project in Java, C# and C++?

Tags: c#, java, c++, documentation

How to manage one consistent documentation for different implementations of one project in Java, C# and C++?

We have projects for which we need to provide versions in Java, C# and C++.

One problem we face is documentation. The C++ version is our main version.
Then we propagate changes to the C# and Java versions. Every time we make
a change to the C++ version we need to do the same for the Java and C# versions.
Is there a way to manage this?

For documenting C++ and C# we use Visual Studio, and javadoc for Java versions.

Comment: You might want to look into [Doxygen](http://www.stack.nl/~dimitri/doxygen/) for documentation. I don't think it has the auto-propagating behavior you're looking for, but it will at least give you some consistency across languages since it supports all three you're using.

Comment: Is that even possible? An idiomatic Java signature like `public <T> void f(Collection<T> x)` would probably look like `template<typename It> void f(It begin, It end)` in C++. How would a unified documentation for `f` look like?

Comment: An `IEnumerable<T>` is a pretty different beast to an iterator pair.

Comment: @DeadMG Are you agreeing or disagreeing with me? :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Doxygen](http://www.doxygen.org/) which provides an uniform, language independent syntax and works for C++, Java and as well for C#.

Comment: Doxygen produces crap that is no more informative than just reading the source or looking at the code completion list yourself.

Comment: @DeadMG: Sure, if you fed it crap documentation.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer to solve this problem using source control tools.

1. I create separate Git repositories for each different language project. In this case, I would start with the C++ repository and then create additional ones for the Java and C# code.
2. Since the C++ code is the "master" (or reference) version, I would open the C# repository and add a new Git submodule for the C++ code. This submodule will always represent how "up-to-date" your C# library is compared to the C++ library. Do the same for the Java library's repository.
3. After changes are made to the C++ code (including documentation), you can examine the submodules for the C# and Java targets. These submodules will show you the commits made to the C++ library since the last time you updated the C# or Java code, allowing you to easily apply and/or verify the changes in the other languages. When you commit the changes to the C# or Java libraries, you can update the submodule reference to point to the new "up-to-date" commit in the C++ library.

This workflow has the great advantage of always informing the entire team about whether or not each library is up-to-date, and if not, exactly what changes need to be made in order to update it.